# Help on this example of gluing varieties

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $V_1=\{(x_1,y_1) \in \mathbb{C}^2\mid y_1^2=x_1^2-3x_1+2\}$ and $V_2=\{(x_2,y_2) \in \mathbb{C}^2\mid y_2^2=2x_2^2-3x_2+1\}$. We set $U_i=\{(x_i,y_i) \mid x_i\neq 0\} \subset V_i,\ i\in\{1,2\}$.

Now, I have shown that $\varphi:U_1\to U_2, (x,y)\mapsto(1/x,y/x)$ is an isomorphism.

The gluing of $V_1$ and $V_2$ alongside of $U_1$ and $U_2$ is then given by

$$V=V_1 \dot{\cup} V_2 / \tilde{},$$

where $u \tilde{} v$ iff $u\in U_1, v=\varphi(u)\in U_2$.

Is there a way to simplify $V$ and write it in a less abstract manner?